# Windows Driver Development: Deploy option missing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, device-driver, wdk, wfp

I was trying to compile and deploy the [WFP sample obtained from MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-Filtering-Platform-ae42c8d7) called `msnmntr` but the same problem applies to all samples.

This and all samples fail to deploy because there's one step [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that are missing in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

It says:

> 1) Open the property pages for your driver package. Right-click the driver package project in Solution Explorer and select Properties.
>
> 2) In the property pages for the driver package, click Configuration Properties, click Driver Install, and then click Deployment.

However there's no such option in the Visual Studio 2012 as you can see in the screen below:

[image]

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I see the same. I suggest you to ask at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/threads

Comment: I have posted there: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/066e9a7d-18f5-4aef-a5f4-2c9df1ae9f65

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the answer I received from Microsoft support.

Open `msnmntr.sln` in Visual Studio.

In Solution Explorer, right-click Solution `msnmntr` (2 projects), and choose `Add > New Project`. Navigate to `Windows Driver > Package`. Add a new Driver Install Package named `msnmntr` Package.

In Solution Explorer, right-click Solution `msnmntr` (2 projects), and choose Configuration Manager. Choose the configuration and platform that you want (Example: Win8 Debug, x64).

In Solution Explorer, right-click `msnmntr` Package, and choose Properties. Navigate to `Configuration Properties > Driver Install > Deployment`. Check `Enable deployment`. Check `Remove previous driver versions before deployment`. Enter the name of your target computer. Select `Do Not Install`.

In Solution Explorer, locate and open `msnmntr.inf`. In the `[Version]` section, add these lines:

```
Class = ActivityMonitor
CatalogFile = msnmntr.cat
```

Just above the `[Strings]` section, add these sections:

```
[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskId1%,,,""

[SourceDisksFiles]
msnmntr.sys = 1,,
```

On the Build menu, choose Build Solution.

Locate the INF file on the target computer (Example: `C:\DriverTest\DriverFiles\msnmntr.inf`).  Right-click the INF file, and choose `Install`.

On the target computer, open a Command Prompt window as Administrator, and enter `net start msnmntr`.

Answer (score 2):

So I had the same problem regarding a sample I am working with. It all came from being confused about what project they actually wanted me to edit. it turns out it wasn't the driver project, but the one called "package". Not sure if you have such a package, but that was the problem in my case.
[image]

Comment: What's inside the package subproject? Mine says it misses the INF file

Comment: No, we're not seeing a "package" project there. By the way, we're using the "stream edit" WFP sample.

Comment: all samples seems to suffer the same problem