# "Deployment" option missing in VS2015+WDK

Tags: visual-studio, device-driver, wdk

I am trying to create a W10-64 driver by VS2015sp2+WDK10. Since I am new with these tools, I am trying to repeat the simple KDMF driver example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/hardware/hh439665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I am facing a problem: "Driver Install" configuration entry contains only "KDMF Verifier" and "UMDF Verifier" (see image below). Other items reported in documentation are missing. In particular, there is nothing about deployment, so I am unable to distribute my driver. Tried to install/unistall/repair both VS2015 and WDK, but without success. I have also tried to add a "Driver Install Package" to the solution, but it is missing the "Deployment" item too. Please note that I am able to compile and also connect to target machine via network and debug it in kernel mode, but I don't know how to produce my package and install it on target.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

NOTE: It seems that something similar happened in VS2012 ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314319/windows-driver-development-deploy-option-missing-in-visual-studio-2012)), but the solution doesn't seem to apply to my case.

[image]

Comment: You found answer?

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]
**NOTE: It turned out that the problem is still there if "All Configurations" or "All Platforms" is selected. Deployment items only appear if a specific Configuration/Platform pair is selected!**

Resolved. Eventually, I had to

1. uninstall WDK10
2. uninstall VS2015
3. reinstall VS2015 (it automatically installed SP2)
4. reinstall WDK10 [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx) (it should install also SDK10, but it turned out that it's incomplete)
5. uninstall SDK10
6. install SDK 8.1 [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk)
7. install SDK 10 [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Now my VS2015 can compile, deploy and debug x86/x64 drivers.

Comment: It doesn't help, is there are any other solution?

Comment: As I said in "note", the items disappear if is not selected a SPECIFIC platform AND a SPECIFIC configuration, at least in my environment. Anyway, in my experience WDK's VisualStudio integration is quite fragile and buggy. I.e. live debugger hangs frequently or crashes. Windgb is still slightly better...

Comment: This option hidden even if I select specific configuration (checked each of them). May be problem is, running on Win7?

Comment: I am running W7 too (x64, fully patched). Did you check if "Platform" is set to a particular value (e.g. x64)?

Answer (score 1):

Change "All Configurations" to anything else, and the "Deployment" option will be available.

[image: Change "All Configurations" to anything else, and the "Deployment" option will be available.]

Comment: Indeed, "All Platforms" OR "All Configurations" is the actual guilty, (see "edit" in my auto-answer above)